# AADSTS65001 invalid_grant when all permissions have admin consent

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to fetch an access token & a refresh token for my app on behalf of a user.
I'm using the following code:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=my-app-id' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=user.read,user.readbasic.all,files.read,files.read.all,files.read.selected,files.readwrite,files.readwrite.all,mail.read,mail.read.shared,mail.readbasic,mail.readwrite,mail.send' \
--data-urlencode 'code=my-code' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=client-secret'
```

Using POSTMAN for now.

and I get the following error response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'my-app-id' named 'testapp'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 86781b44-3989-4b54-b905-697beba50400\r\nCorrelation ID: bbe88855-3d61-4f13-85c1-05e48245e1a1\r\nTimestamp: 2021-04-15 01:40:45Z",
    "error_codes": [
        65001
    ],
    "timestamp": "2021-04-15 01:40:45Z",
    "trace_id": "86781b44-3989-4b54-b905-697beba50400",
    "correlation_id": "bbe88855-3d61-4f13-85c1-05e48245e1a1",
    "suberror": "consent_required",
    "claims": "{\"access_token\":{\"capolids\":{\"essential\":true,\"values\":[\"809ad5c7-1cbd-4502-a52f-f749fa4b5049\"]}}}"
}
```

All of my API permissions that I'm using in the scope have admin consent.

I believe this is a bug, because previously I got the same error when I was only using the "User.Read,offline_access" scopes, both of which had admin consent. However, after removing "offline_access" scope everything worked fine and I was able to retrieve the refresh token.

But now, the error is back and I'm not sure what the issue could be.

I have tried to check the parameters and gave admin consent again but nothing worked.

Please advise if you know what I should do.

Thank you.

[Ms Graph permissions consent Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGZPx.png)

EDIT: Removing "v2.0" from the url, leaving it just to be "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token" has worked.. but im not sure if this is correct to do? any risks?

ANSWER:
Scopes were comma separated, they should have been space separated. Here's the cURL that worked:

```
curl --location --request POST 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' 
--data-urlencode 'client_id=xx-x-xx-x' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=user.read user.readbasic.all files.read files.read.all files.read.selected files.readwrite files.readwrite.all mail.read mail.read.shared mail.readbasic mail.readwrite mail.readwrite.shared mail.send mail.send.shared' \
--data-urlencode 'code=CODEHERE' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=SECRET'
```

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Check the update of my answer, if you have any questions, please feel free to call me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Azure AD graph** which has been deprecated. It is recommended that you use the latest **microsoft graph**.

First, run admin consent url in the browser. This will grant the application the consent of the administrator within the scope of the tenant.
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/adminconsent?client_id={client id}&state=12345&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`.

Next, you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token,which requires you to log in to the user and obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

1.Request an authorization code in the browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client app client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

2.Redeem token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/token 

client_id={client id}
&scope=openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&code={code}
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret={client_secret}
```

---

**Add:**

By the way, I just recommend that you use the latest version. Of course, if  you use the old version: `https://login.windows.net`, also there is no problem.

In addition, if you delete `v2.0` from the url, it just means that you will use the `v1.0` endpoint to obtain the token,   which is not inherently risky and you can use it with confidence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer, but I thought I was using microsoft graph, I actually got the API request straight from the docs. Did you notice that I was using the deprecated Azure AD graph because of the `login.windows.net` ? or was it something else?


I will try what you suggested and come back here to select your answer as the answer once it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it's not working for me, it still gives me the same error of invalid grant due to not consenting :/

Comment: @HamzehMuaz   Are you calling Azure Active Directory Graph api `https://graph.windows.net/` or Microsoft Graph api `https://graph.microsoft.com/`?

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  AAD graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbxDs.png.         microsoft  graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iumgv.png

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  Did you run the administrator consent url?

Comment: I'm using https://graph.microsoft.com/ per your instructions, and I have checked the API permissions and they are for Microsoft Graph not Azure AD Graph.
I did run the consent url but the result is still the same.
I don't think this is an issue with consent though, all of my scopes have admin consent already, which is weird.

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  Can you use the process I provided in the answer to get the token?

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  Go to AAD portal>your app>API permissions to provide screenshots.

Comment: I have used the process that you provided to get the token already, same result.

I added a screenshot as an edit to the original question under "Ms Graph permissions consent Image"

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  Is it still AADTS65001 error?

Comment: Yes sir, still is.

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  I think this is the reason for the `scope`. What if only one permission is set? For example: `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/files.read`, test it!

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  Also, I see you are using a user account. What if you use an administrator account?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not tried that and I cannot try it, I do not have administrator privileges in my organization.
The account that I'm automating also does not have administrator access.
I always thought that admin consent is sufficient when using a normal user, am I wrong to assume that?

Comment: @HamzehMuaz  Your idea is also correct. Have you tried to set the `scope` to: `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/files.read` ,test it!

Comment: Perfect! What you suggested has worked and it opened my eyes to try and see if my scopes were the issue, and indeed I should have been using space-separated and not comma-separated. so I changed "Mail.read,Mail.send" to "Mail.read Mail.send"
So, the scopes were the issue.
Thank you Mr. Carl.